# Craps probability: What value of x makes this a fair game?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You are playing Craps at the casino. In each round of Craps, two 6-sided
dice are rolled. You place a bet as follows: You wager 1 dollar. If a 5 is
rolled you win x dollars. If a 7 is rolled, you loose your money. Otherwise,
you get your dollar back. What value of x makes this a fair game?

This is how I approached the problem:

To have two dice sum to 5, there are 4 different possibilities,

Therefore P(5) = $\frac{4}{36}$

To have two dice sum to 7, there are 6 different possibilities,

Therefore P(7) = $\frac{6}{36}$

The probability of winning is $\frac{P(5)}{P(5) + P(7)}$ = $\frac{4}{10}$

Now I am a little confused about how to find the x to make this a fair game? Do I find the expected value to get the x?

Like this: X(5) = x; X(7) = 0;

$1 =\frac{4}{10} * x$

$x = \frac{10}{4}$

Comment: Let random variable $W$ be the "net" amount that you win. Find the $x$ such that $E(W)=0$. Your computation of the conditional probability $4/10$ can be used, but is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

The probabilities are correct.

Now the profit $X$ is $0$ for all throws that are not 5 or 7,
the profit is $x - 1$ when 5 pays out $x$. The profit is $-1$ if 7 is rolled.

So $E(X) = 0\cdot(1 - P(5) - P(7)) + (x - 1)\cdot P(5) + -1\cdot P(7)$

This equals $\frac{4}{36}x - \frac{4}{36} - \frac{6}{36}$, and this should equal $0$ for a fair game....

Answer (score 0):

You are right. But let things be clearer.

Let assume you bet $1$ dollar, and that you will receive a random gain $X$. Then we say that game is fair if your expected gain is equal to your initial bet i.e $$1=\mathbb{E}[X]$$

Here in your case :

$$X =\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} x & \text{with probability} & \frac{4}{36} \\
0 & \text{with probability} & \frac{6}{36} \\
1 & \text{with probability} & 1-\frac{4}{36}-\frac{6}{36}=\frac{26}{36} \\
\end{array}\right.$$

we then get that game is fair if :

$$1=\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{4}{36}x +\frac{26}{36}\times 1 \Rightarrow x=\frac{10}{4} $$